# Why doesn't lookup filter work on visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, filters, salesforce2salesforce

I am trying to develop few look up fields on Visualforce page.

**Requirements:**

1. The first lookup field shows all partner Accounts.
2. The second lookup field is filtered to show only Contacts associated with the Account selected in step 1.

**Example:**

Suppose I select *Partner Account1* from the 1st lookup. The next lookup field should show up with partner contacts associated with *Partner Account1* (i.e. *Partner Contact1*).

**Current Behavior**

Instead the second lookup is showing me all of the existing contacts under Partner accounts, and is not filtering by the value selected in the first lookup.

Comment: Images might help, I'm having trouble following your question.

Comment: some source code may help too. (and starting a new line now and then)

Comment: If anyone know the answer please post your answers.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to display the first lookup field in the visulaforce page as Apex:inputField 
I had the same issue and by displayin the field in my page the second lookup with filter worked properly !
p.s : you cannot hide it (display:"none" or rendered="false") and you can not make it outputFiled 
I know it sucks !

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, you are using the salesforce's lookup filters then your current behavior is exactly how it is supposed to work. 
Salesforce will let you choose any contact from the lookup dialog irrespective of the account selection. It is only when you try to save the record will it validate to make sure that the chosen contact indeed belongs to the chosen account. If not, it will throw an error message. 
However if you want, you can over ride the lookup dialog for the contact field to display only for the chosen account.